# Getting errors when trying to plot hypocycloid in a Manipulate expression

Tags: manipulate, warning-messages, parametric-functions

```
Manipulate[
  ParametricPlot[
    {(R - r) Cos[theta] + rCos[((R - r)/r) theta],
     (R - r) Sin[theta] + rSin[((R - r)/r) theta]},
    {theta, 0, 2 pi},
    {R, 1, 770},
    {r, 1, 770}],
  ColorFunction -> "AtlanticColors"]
```

I'm attempting to manipulate a hypocycloid in Mathematica, but I keep getting an error message saying there are more options expected from variable `r`. I'm fairly new to Mathematica, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should use only $\theta$ as a varible in `ParametricPlot`. Also include `ColorFunction` inside it, not in Manipulate...

Answer (score 1):

You should use the integer $k=R/r$ to control the number of cusps. Try:

```
Manipulate[
ParametricPlot[{r (k - 1) Cos[theta] + r Cos[(k - 1) theta], 
r (k - 1) Sin[theta] - r Sin[(k - 1) theta]}, {theta, 0, 2 Pi}, 
ColorFunction -> "AtlanticColors"], {k, 3, 15, 1}, {r, 1, 770}]
```

[image]

if $k$ is allowed to be a noninteger too:

```
Manipulate[
ParametricPlot[{r (k - 1) Cos[theta] + r Cos[(k - 1) theta], 
r (k - 1) Sin[theta] - r Sin[(k - 1) theta]}, {theta, 0, 2 Pi}, 
ColorFunction -> "AtlanticColors"], {k, 3, 15}, {r, 1, 770}]
```

[image]

Comment: Bless your soul, you just saved my math grade. Is there a way to do it without controlling the number of cusps and allowing for arbitrary smaller circle values? Also, since there are at least two ways to plot a hypocycloid with x number of cusps (one with no intersections and one that looks like a hyped up star), is there a way to account for that? Thanks so much for your reply!

Comment: You are welcome. Sure that the hypocycloid can be drawn without $k$ being an integer. Just use `{k,3,15}`, thus $r$ can take any value including an integer, indicating de number of cups.